# How to use a function from Component inside the page controller in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components

I want to use a function from a component inside my **page.controller**
First, I don't know if it is possible? and Second, if it is possible, how should I do that?

Here I have have function inside the **component.controller** called `checkStatus`, I want to execute it, therefore my `ng-disabled` turns `false` and I can click on `SAVE` button.

**testComponent.component.js:**

```
export default {
  template: temp,
  controller: myComponentController,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindings: {
    popupMsg : '&'
  }
};

function myComponentController() {
  'ngInject';

  this.popupMsg = function() {
    alert("It is working!");
    this.checkStatus();
  };

  this.checkStatus = function() {
    this.mustPass = true;
  };

}
```

**myPage.controller.js:**

```
export class MyPageController {

  constructor() {
    'ngInject'
    ...
  }

  save() {
    ...
  }
}
```

**myPage.html:**

```
<form>
<test-component mandatory="vm.popupMsg()"> </test-component>

<div>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="vm.save()" ng-disabled="!vm.mustPass"> Save </button>
</div>
</form>
```

[**Plunker for testing**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ThhcfuksuYWhsLk91emf?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have [output bindings](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) on your testComponent.

**testComponent.component.js**

```
bindings: {
  statusChange: '&'

}

function myComponentController() {

     this.checkStatus = function() {
        this.mustPass = true;
        this.statusChange({$event: this.mustPass});
    };
```

**mypage.html**

```
<test-component mandatory="vm.popupMsg()" status-change="vm.onStatusChange($event)"> </test-component>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work at all. Never change to `true`

Comment: [Updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/phLwjTo0vCYc2Ds9V35e?p=preview)